# What does Skype on Mac do with Webcams?

Tags: macos, skype, webcam

I don't know if many of you have had this problem: After starting Skype, you can no longer use the webcam you specified for Skype to use in other applications such as Quick Time Player.

Even completely closing Skype doesn't release it, you actually have to completely reboot your machine.

The question I have is: What the hell does Skype do with webcams and has anybody found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that problem at all! Skype video call > Photo Booth > Skype video call works fine!

Remove Skype fully (preferences and AppSupport usw) and then reinstall? Or use an older version.

Comment: How is going to solve the problem ?